# ¿Cómo puedo incluir todos los datos en un análisis de regresión en R, incluso si no se ajusta a la línea?

Tags: r, rstudio

Datos típicos RStudio

Este es un ejercicio con datos inventados, pero he logrado que lo demás datos concuerde menos esos 3. Actualmente tengo un p-value de "p-value: 0.9991" y los demás datos si genera un efecto de línea diagonal, la intensión es tener todos los datos allí y no que me quede 3 datos por fuera

[image: Imagen de R-Studio]

```
library(readxl)
file <- "C:/Users/alfre/Downloads/Juana/baseDatos.xlsx"
datos <- read_excel(file)
head(datos) #Muestra las 6 primeras lineas

id_persona<- read_excel(file) #Variable dependiente
names(id_persona)

pairs(id_persona)
cor(id_persona)

regresion <- lm(id_persona ~ edad, data = id_persona) #Variable independiente edad
summary(regresion)

plot(id_persona$edad, id_persona$id_persona, xlab='edad', ylab='id_persona')
abline(regresion)

confint(regresion)
anova(regresion)

residuos <- rstandard(regresion)
valores.ajustados <- fitted(regresion)
plot(valores.ajustados, residuos)

qqnorm(residuos)
qqline(residuos)
```

[image: Imagen del excel]

Comment: SI he entendido bien, los datos son los que son, si quieres que esos 3 elementos que desentonan con el resto encajen en la recta vas a tener que cambiarlos, tal vez hacer log(de los datos) o alguna otra transformación, o directamente eliminarlos.